# UI automated testing within SharePoint

Tags: .net, sharepoint, ui-automation

I'm looking for automated Functional Testing tools that can manipulate SharePoint sites, libraries, and documents thought the web interface.  It needs to be extensible enough to handle any custom pieces that are added later.  This does not need to be specifically for sharepoint, but it is necessary that it is to work within a SharePoint context.  I saw someone post up about Selenium in another thread, I am not too familiar with that product.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a crack with Visual Studio 2010. It is in Beta now, so downloadable. It has a new product that will create web front end tests.

Comment: I selected this as the answer as it most closely aligns with the current work environment.

Answer (score 3):

The company that I am currently at is using Selenium [(link)](http://seleniumhq.org/) and being fairly successful.  According to what I understand about the product, Selenium should be a fine tool for testing SharePoint sites.

At a previous company, we used WatiN [(link)](http://watin.sourceforge.net/), which proved to be easier to use and more seamless than Selenium due to the fact that it's implemented in .NET.  Selenium, on the other hand, is implemented with java with the option to use .NET assemblies to communicate with the Selenium engine.

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the links, after doing some research I don't believe Selenium would be the best choice moving forward.  Also we had written some pieces in WatiN and replaced them with PowerShell.  However, the learning curve seemed to hurt production.  Thanks for the information though

Answer (score 2):

I have just created a guidance project http://sharetest.codeplex.com. You may find some useful stuff in there!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this book on [scripted GUI testing with Ruby.](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/idgtr/scripted-gui-testing-with-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

I work in PHP and my group has been using Selenium with some success over the past year as well. It allows you to easily write/record automated UI tests (you can get plugins for Firefox, for example, which let you record tests right from the browser), and retrieve document values for comparison.